# What is the parametrization of the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $L^p$-(semi)norm $1$ for any $p$?

Tags: lp-spaces, parametric

I'm looking for a curve $t_p: [0,L] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that describes the set

$T_p = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x|^p + |y|^p = 1\}.$

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the set $T_p$ goes by the name ([*superellipse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)) or *Lamé curve*.

The parametrization is:

$$
x(\theta) = \pm \cos^{2/n} \theta \\
y(\theta) = \pm \sin^{2/n} \theta \\
\text{ for } 0 \le \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}
$$